# Regex to allow only dots, letters and dashes in VB.NET

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have that code, and it only dimiss words with spaces and that it starts with +... But I have to allow only dots, letters and dashes... I think that its more simple:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Contactos

    ReadOnly pattern As String = "\s([^+\d\,]+),?"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cadena As String = " " & TextBox1.Text & ","

        Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(cadena, pattern)

        Do While match.Success
            frmMain.ListBox1.Items.Add(match.Groups(1).ToString)
            match = match.NextMatch()
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

What can I do?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following pattern `"(?<=(^|,\s))(?<word>[\.A-Za-z\-]+)($|,)"` and use named group `word` to get expected values:

```
    Do While match.Success
        frmMain.ListBox1.Items.Add(match.Groups("word").ToString)
        match = match.NextMatch()
    Loop
```

Comment: `\w` stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.

Comment: I have that: "^(.*\s+.*)+$" But Idk how to add it to the pattern... :(

Comment: Could you please provide us some sample data, it will help us to find the right solution

Comment: Well I have that words: +3456565, two words, a.nick, word... The only words that I want to filter are: a.nick & word... How can I do that?
I have that: "\s([\.A-Za-z\-_:\ \s]+),?"

Comment: Nope, I don't have that I wan't I have that: (?<=(^|,\s))(?<word>[\.A-Za-zÑ-ñ0-9\-_:]+)($|,) But when I put my string, the app only adds commas. What can I do?

Comment: Did you used named group `word` to get an expected value?

Comment: I think so, but Idk, I'm very newbie sorry, this is that I have: http://pastebin.com/AMEvEB1e Can you check it for me? Thanks! :) The strange thing here is that: http://rubular.com/r/5E3t8hoMe0 It works, Idk why.. D:

Comment: Please see my update: `Groups("word")`. It is how named groups are used.

Comment: Oh, it was that... Thaaaanks! :DDD

Comment: I have one more problem, if I add for example: one, two, three In the listbox, only appears two and three... What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ReadOnly pattern As String = "\s([\.\-A-Za-z]+),?"
```

In the first answer the "\w" pattern will match letters, numbers and underscore. The "A-Za-z" portion I gave you will match letters only.